# What is the dot-notation between class names and what does it mean?

Tags: java, android, syntax

What is the meaning of this .notation (AlertDialog.Builder) in a class constructor?

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
        .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
        .create();

}
```

Does it mean that the Builder class is defined inside the AlertDialog class? Or Builder is a method, but its first letter is capitalized so I'm confused.

Comment: Look out for Builder pattern.

Comment: That's [fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). They just inserted line breaks for clarity.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976150/benefits-and-drawbacks-of-method-chaining-and-a-possibility-to-replace-all-void) for more information on method chaining and remember that whitespace largly has no meaning to the compiler. Imagine it all on one line

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This pattern is called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).

Builder is a static inner class of AlertDialog.

Each method in Builder returns a Builder (usually "this") instead of void.

Answer (score 2):

This means that Builder is a static nested class in AlertDialog class, that is

```
class AlertDialog {

   static class Builder {
..
```

Answer (score 0):

`Builder` is a static inner class of the `AlertDialog` class.

I advise you to read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) about the use and the utility of nested classes

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)!

`Builder` is a static class defined within the `AlertDialog` class. You are calling it's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This is [Builder design pattern](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/builder-design-pattern-in-java.html).

What you do in your code:

- Create instance of the Builder class - `new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())`
- Set its properties calling `setTitle` and `setPositiveButton`
- Create instance of `AlertDialog` by calling `create()` method with the properties of the Builder.

> **Builder pattern** is a creational design pattern it means it solves problem related to object creation. Constructors in Java are used to create object and can take parameters required to create object. Problem starts when an Object can be created with lot of parameters, some of them may be mandatory and others may be optional. Builder Design pattern should be used when number of parameter required in constructor is more than manageable usually 4 or at most 5.