# Understanding Java notation

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use dialogs in Android.  In the process, I encountered lines of code like the following:

```
alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",new...
```

This notation is a bit strange for me as an old C++ programmer. Is this the same as,

```
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click yes to exit!");
alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new...
```

If so, is this notation part of Java or unique to Android programming? What is the name of this notation (or method)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: The benefits and drawbacks of this are discussed here; [Benefits and drawbacks of method chaining and a possibility to replace all void return parameters by the object itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976150/benefits-and-drawbacks-of-method-chaining-and-a-possibility-to-replace-all-void)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This idiom is called [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) and it's not specific to Java or Android. The trick is making methods that otherwise would return void return a reference to `this`, permitting long chains of method calls to the same object.

This idiom is quite useful when used in the [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), like in your example. It's also a building block when designing [fluent interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Comment: Specifically this is the Builder pattern in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can do same with C++ as well just return same object (this pointer). 
So ultimately you are calling next function on returned this pointer.

It is used in Builder Design Pattern!

Answer (score 1):

In fact the code is:

```
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Click yes to exit!").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes",new...
```

Maybe the formatting made you wonder. As you can see, and as mentioned by the other answers, the `setMessage()` apparently returns the `alertDialogBuilder` making it possible to call another method on it.