# How to chain methods in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have a question about how is the best way to realize it.

```
class name {
  public function method($a){ 
    $this->a = $a; 
  }
  public function two($b){
    $this->b = $b;
  }
}
```

How I call `$class->method('a')->two('b');` ?

```
return __CLASS__; // self?
```

on every method? or what? idk what is the best way or how all frameworks realize it.

If anyone can guide me I'll be very greatful... thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's done by returning `$this` in every method.

```
class name {
  public function method($a){ 
    $this->a = $a;
    return $this; 
  }
  public function two($b){
    $this->b = $b;
    return $this; 
  }
}
```

Anyway there are many opponents (including me) of this convention for a few reasons.

Comment: I'm curious as to what your reasons against this convention are. Personally I've been using this convention  since my C++ days.

Comment: Search for "method chaining". There's a lot of discussion on the Internet. Here an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976150/benefits-and-drawbacks-of-method-chaining-and-a-possibility-to-replace-all-void