# PropertyDescriptor vs. setter that returns a value

Tags: java, reflection, javabeans, java-7, introspection

I have to port a lot of code from java6 to java7. Java6 has no problem with setters, returning values. So this example code:

```
public class Main {
public static class MyDummy {
    private String payload;

    public String getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public boolean setPayload(String payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
        return true;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("JAVA: " + System.getProperty("java.version") + " (" + System.getProperty("java.vm.name") + ")");
    MyDummy d = new MyDummy();
    d.setPayload("init");
    System.out.println("Value before: " + d.getPayload());

    try {
        PropertyDescriptor pd = new PropertyDescriptor("payload", MyDummy.class);
        pd.getWriteMethod().invoke(d, "hello introspection");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    }
    System.out.println("Value after: " + d.getPayload());

}
}
```

results awaited output at java 6:

```
JAVA: 1.6.0_24 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM)
Value before: init
Value after: hello introspection
```

Unfortunately (for me) at java 7 output is:

```
JAVA: 1.7.0_06 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM)
Value before: init
Exception: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setPayload
Value after: init
```

So introspection does not work anymore for setters, that return anything but void. My questions is what shall i do? The firs idea is to wrap setter in void-setter. Like this:

```
public void setPayload(String payload) {
    setPayloadImpl(payload); // ignoring return value
}
public boolean setPayloadImpl(String payload) {
    this.payload = payload;
    return true;
}
```

But this solutioin forces to change the setter-name(overload methods by retrun type is not possible) and bloat the source code whith such setter-wrappers. Could you suggest a better solution?

P.S. Strange that it does not mentioned in [java7 compatibility list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html).

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806895/why-did-propertydescriptor-behavior-change-from-java-1-6-to-1-7. See the bugreport that was mentioned there: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7172865