# IntrospectionException: Method not found: setLastModified

Tags: ibm-midrange, jtopen, ibm-ifs

Our server was updated to java 8 and the code below no longer works.  I am using the latest version of jtopen and can not get it to work in java 7 or 8.

The code uses the jtopen (java toolkit) to access the integrated file system on the IBM i.

```
AS400 as400 = new AS400("myip","myuser","mypassword")
IFSFile file = new IFSFile(as400, params.path);     
if (file.exists()){
    Ifs ifs = new Ifs()
       ifs.CopyFile(as400,params.path,response)
       as400.disconnectAllServices();
}
else {
    redirect(action: "fileNotFound")
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setLastModified.
>   Stacktrace follows: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
>   **Caused by: java.lang.Error: java.beans.IntrospectionException: Method not found: setLastModified**
>           at com.ibm.as400.access.IFSFileBeanInfo.(IFSFileBeanInfo.java:126)
>   ~[jt400-8.7.jar:JTOpen 8.7]
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>           at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.instantiate(InstanceFinder.java:96)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>           at com.sun.beans.finder.InstanceFinder.find(InstanceFinder.java:66)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>           at java.beans.Introspector.findExplicitBeanInfo(Introspector.java:448)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>           at java.beans.Introspector.(Introspector.java:398) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>           at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>           at PageController.getBoardReport(PageController.groovy:113) ~[main/:na]

Any ides how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Java beans infrastructure changed in 1.7 to require that setter methods have a return type of void (see [Why did PropertyDescriptor behavior change from Java 1.6 to 1.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806895/why-did-propertydescriptor-behavior-change-from-java-1-6-to-1-7)). The setLastModified method has a return type of boolean to match the similar method in java.io.File. A fix for IFSFileBeanInfo.java has been checked into the JTOpen CVS respository.   You will either need to build JTOpen yourself, ask IBM service for a jt400.jar containing the fix, or wait for the next release of JTOpen.

Comment: Problem Solved: I placed an IBM i support call and they provided me with the .jar file.   Excellent support service!