# Chaining method pattern

Tags: java, builder, chaining

Does creating chainable methods make the execution poorly?

I'm talking about this:

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo bar() {
       // Code
       return this;
    }

    public Foo setBar() {
       // Code
       return this;
    }
}

Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.bar().setBar();
```

Is this better than creating a `Foo.Builder` class and get the `Foo` object with a `Builder.getFoo();` method?

Answer (score 2):

This sort of pattern, called a [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) makes the code much more readable. Unfortunately, the JavaBeans standard, which is very widely used, specifies that setters must have a `void` return, and returning `this` can break some tools that expect to match the exact signature. [There's a good overview here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741369/does-java-beans-setter-permit-return-this).

Answer (score 1):

There are no efficiency concerns in regular java in doing this. The reason to go with a `Builder` pattern (`StringBuilder`), etc is because of the way your class functions (immutability of `String`), which might make certain operations inefficient.