# What do ".and" and "where" stand for?

Tags: java

I can't understand the following code:

```
final Specifications<PaymentBatch> criteriaSpecification = 
        where(paymentBatchesInZone(getCurrentZone()))
        .and(new PaymentBatchSearchFilter(paymentBatchSearchQueryDTO));
```

What do `.and` and `where` stand for?

Comment: It's just a method on whatever class `where` returns.

Comment: @blm Actually, what `and` returns...

Comment: @falsarella The result of the entire expression is what `and` returns, `and` is a method on what `where` returns. I could have made my comment clearer, but that's what my comment means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pattern called [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent%5Finterface).

For details see here: [Is it bad practice to make a setter return "this"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345001/is-it-bad-practice-to-make-a-setter-return-this)

Every call to a function returns the current object so subsequent method calls may be made without having a separate reference declared.

Thus both methods `where()` and `and()` are parts of a [DAO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) and provide the means to create an SQL `WHERE` statement.