# Why don't Java setters return the Object's instance by default to chain commands?

Tags: java

An automatically generated setter in some popular IDEs may look like this:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Is there any disadvantage at all to doing the following?

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Person setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        return this;
    }
}
```

If not, why is it not more widespread? The advantage of being able to chain commands together seems very convenient at first glance. Thank you in advance for your insights.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345001/is-it-bad-practice-to-make-a-setter-return-this

Comment: I vaguely remember both Eclipse and IntelliJ giving the option to do this "Builder Patter", is what it is called.

Comment: Because that's not how a setter is defined in the Java bean specification, on which many, many Java technologies and frameworks rely.

Comment: There is a whole bunch of setters in Java NIO that do exactly that.

Comment: @EJP but AFAIK those are not following the get/set name convention. Thanks for pointing this out, now I finally understood why their names are like that.